# Протокол регистрации на сервере телефонии sip

Tags: sip

Я не могу понять как авторизоваться на сервере sip. В описании написано, что надо отправить тестовый запрос `REGISTER`, и на него придёт ответ с тем, что нет логина с паролем, но что самое важное, так это придет `nonce`. Я в rfc не нашел описание, какой надо запрос отправлять для сервера, и в интернете нет описания. даже на хабре нет. никто не знаю как будто. я много уже что перепробовал и так и не понял, что надо в запросе отправить, чтобы пришел `nonce`, чтобы я мог сделать запрос нормальный. я начал делать свою библиотеку, потому что так и не понял как использовать чужие. вот что я отправляю на сервер и что приходит.

```
->REGISTER sip:sip.zadarma.com SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/TCP 160104@sip.zadarma.com:5060;branch=Z8dna3DHbNFo
Authorization: Digest username="160104", realm="sip.zadarma.com", uri="sip:160104@sip.zadarma.com"
CSeq: 1826 REGISTER

<-202:SIP/2.0 400 Missing Required Header in Request
Via: SIP/2.0/TCP 160104@sip.zadarma.com:5060;branch=Z8dna3DHbNFo;received=89.221.20.15
CSeq: 1826 REGISTER
Server: Zadarma server
Content-Length: 0
```

Comment: Лучше разберитесь с belle-sip, потому как сам sip имеет огромное количество нюансов, вы рискуете утонуть

Comment: @gbg я пробовал belle-sip, не понятно как подключиться и авторизоваться, хотя часть работы всё же сделал, но не смог авторизоваться. документации нет, а примеры, нет примера с авторизацией. как вообще разобраться в этом?

Comment: Берете исходники линфона и смотрите. Особняком стоит вопрос, для чего вам понадобилось с нуля ваять sip-телефон, когда на свете их существуют десятки, как платных, так и бесплатных, на разные платформы, в том числе и на веб

Comment: @gbg потому что документации нет, и не понятно как с ней работать. но у меня уже получилось получить nonce, я нашел отчёт один пользователя о том, что перестал linphone работать, и посмотрел что отправляется для получения nonce. да, что-то облегчить себе работу, лучше посмотреть в сторону готовой библиотеки. что я наверное и сделаю, надо глянуть исходники linphone.

Comment: @gbg ещё увидел что у linphone есть liblinphone, может даже её использовать.